# Chrome content scripts aren't working: DOMContentLoaded listener does not execute

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am trying to code extension that corrects misspellings on 1 forum.

I am trying to access `<p>` tag, with content script, but it doesn't change anything (using the code below):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("P")[4].innerHTML = "correct_word"; 
});
```

It doesn't change anything when added as an extension, apparently if I `wget` the page, and put the script there, all works. Any thoughts?

My *manifest.json* file:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Extension",
    "description": "Description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "matches": ["http://example.com/"],
        "js": ["script.js"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["Filedeleted(really).html"]
}
```

I know content scripts and WWW pages have different sandboxes, maybe content script can't access page (and tag)?

Answer (score 63):

You are injecting your script after the event you are listening for fires (in this case, [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)). Thus, any code that you have in the listener will not be executed, because the event never fires after you have added your listener.

In Chrome extensions and Firefox WebExtensions, when specifying a time for a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to be injected, you can specify `"document_start"`, `"document_end"`, or `"document_idle"`.<sup>1</sup> In a *manifest.json* this is the value stated for the `run_at` property. For [`tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), it is the `runAt` property.

- `document_start`
  The injection takes place prior to the DOM being created, or scripts from the page being run. This means that `document.body` and `document.head` do not yet exist. The `DOMContentLoaded` and `window` `load` events have not yet fired. You can add things to the DOM by adding them to the `document.documentElement`. You may need to use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for the elements you are interested in being added to the DOM, or wait for an event like `DOMContentLoaded` to indicate that the DOM is available.
- `document_end` (default)
  The injection takes place after the DOM is complete, but before subresources (e.g. images and frames) are loaded. This is usually after `DOMContentLoaded` has fired, but before the `window` `load` event fires.
- `document_idle`
  The injection takes place sometime after `document_end` and immediately after the `window` `load` event fires. The [answer to "When does a run_at: document_idle content script run?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248636/3773011) indicates that this is the earlier of:

  - After the `window` `load` event fires, or
  - 200ms after the `DOMContentLoaded` event fired.

  This means that your content script will be injected after `DOMContentLoaded` has fired, but the `window` `load` event may, or may not, have already fired.

### When listening for [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), or `window` `load`, you should check [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) first

Any time you use a `DOMContentLoaded` listener, or a `window` `load` listener, you should always check the [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) prior to adding the listener to make sure that you are adding the listener prior to the `DOMContentLoaded` event being fired (or prior to the `load` event being fired, if that is what you are listening for).  This should be normal habit when you want to listen for these events. If you add the listener after the event has fired, the listener will never be run.

#### For adding a `DOMContentLoaded` listener, you should use something like:

```js
if(document.readyState === 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',afterDOMLoaded);
} else {
    afterDOMLoaded();
}

function afterDOMLoaded(){
    //Everything that needs to happen after the DOM has initially loaded.
}
```

#### For adding a `window` `load` listener, you could use something like:

```js
if(document.readyState !== 'complete') {
    window.addEventListener('load',afterWindowLoaded);
} else {
    afterWindowLoaded();
}

function afterWindowLoaded(){
    //Everything that needs to happen after the window is fully loaded.
}
```

---

1. If you are using `tabs.executeScript()`, the value that you provide for `runAt` only indicates the earliest you want the script to be injected. If you are executing `tabs.executeScript()` prior to that time, then the injection is delayed until the specified time. Note that for `document_start` the point when executing `tabs.executeScript()` will be valid for a new page is a complex topic, which deserves its own question/answer.
2. Portions of this answer were copied from [my answer to "Detect and handle a button click in the active HTML page"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42559512/3773011).