# Chrome extension linker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hello i am trying to develop a chrome extension i am new in this so please be patient with me, and sorry for my bad english as far this is what i have done:

manifest.json

```
    {
    "name": "Linker ",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "LInker",
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",

    },

    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://example.com"],

      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ],

    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

myscript.js

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    chrome.tabs.update({url: "https://example.com"});
    window.close(); 
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('bt_click').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

My idea was when the plugin is running on on a certain website,using contenent script, once a button is pressed on this specific website to open an other website on the same tab or a new tab.

The problem is that nothinng happens when i do this now what i am doing wrong? 
I want that the plugin once is enabled will run always when a specific website is working.
I dont understand please any help would be great!!!!

Comment: what have you done so far to debug it? look at the official documentation on how or why not to use oncontentloaded. lots of existing answers on s.o. already answer that.

Comment: i have seen the console, there is no errors also i have seen the official documentation but no anwers over this can you please give me any link on s.o.  that would be very helpfull i still dont understand why its not working what am i doing wrong? any ideas what  would be the issue? thanks

Comment: Duplicate, but answer is not up-voted or accepted, so can't use it as a dup-target, yet: [Chrome content scripts aren't working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43233115)

Comment: some basic debugging tips: 1) breakpoint inside document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' to see if its even getting hit. 2) verify that the html element actually exists (document.getElementById('bt_click')), there are many reasons why it might not yet be there. Deal with those.

Comment: great ok step 2 yes ofc there is the ID of the button its bt_click 100%,

Comment: but how do do breakpoint inside document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'  where can i view that? any reference please?

Answer (score 0):

If myscript.js is supposed to run as a content script, then there's no need to use this:

```
chrome.tabs.update({url: "https://example.com"});
```

To open some url in the current tab, just execute:

```
// someUrl is your url
location.href = someUrl
```

So modify your script in the following way:

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    location.href = 'http://example.com';
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('bt_click').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

FYI: this code is used in background scripts:

```
chrome.tabs.update
```