# DOMContentLoaded not working in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I am trying to save and return to the current page position whenever a specific page of my application is reloaded (in this case via a form submission). I got this JS code using DOMContentLoaded to work on Chrome and Firefox, however, it is still not working on my iPhone. As in when the form is submitted on my iPhone, the page doesn't automatically scroll back down on reload to the previously saved position as it does on Chrome and Firefox.

```js
<script>
  function afterDOMLoaded() {
    var scrollpos = sessionStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
    if (scrollpos) {
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollpos);
        sessionStorage.removeItem('scrollpos');
    }
    
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('scrollpos', window.scrollY);
    });
  }
  
  if(document.readyState === 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',afterDOMLoaded);
  } else {
      afterDOMLoaded();
  }
</script>
```

After some searching, I discovered the original JS was not working because the DOMContentLoaded event would fire before the event listener got called. However, with the workaround code above the error should be fixed on iOS Safari as well right?

I have cleared all site data of my application from Safari on my iPhone after pushing the updated code to production. However, it is still not working on my iPhone but works fine on Chrome and Firefox using my desktop and Android phone. Does anyone know why the code above is not working on my iPhone and how I can fix it?

Findings on this topic:

- [Chrome content scripts aren't working: DOMContentLoaded listener does not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233115/chrome-content-scripts-arent-working-domcontentloaded-listener-does-not-execut)
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651215

Comment: "Not working" as in, the event handler callback itself still doesn't execute, or as in, what you are trying to _do_ inside the callback function, doesn't work/behave as expected?

Comment: Not working as in the page doesn't automatically scroll back down to the saved position in Safari as it does in other browsers. I only have an iPhone so I can't really check to running JS to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS does not support "onbeforeunload" on iPhone. Therefore, I replaced "onbeforeunload" with "pagehide" and this solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).